# Magento 2: What is the most functional syntax for creating an admin grid?

Tags: magento2.3

I've seen lots of tutorials online, used mage2gen and read over the developer docs. Admin grids seem to have evolved over time. I'm just wondering if there are any suggestions on building a solid admin grid that has functional filtering, pagination, search and mass action. Ideally with minimal XML required.

I've read this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html but really seems light on details. Plus I've seen several implementations in M2 git.

The grids generated by mage2gen seem dated. Going back a page is buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now sticking with mage2gen.

It's an amazing tool. Hopefully will some movement on git issue at some point.

https://github.com/krukas/Mage2Gen/issues/279

It will get you 80% there with admin  grids.